# The [hacking] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

A recent question about a possibly compromised phone was tagged `hacking`. I wondered why we would have that, and it turns out the word refers to just riding a horse for fun. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasure_riding . I think at the least we should update the usage guidance to include this. But since there is only one question in the tag, should we perhaps change it to a less-specific horse riding tag? There are only 13 questions tagged horses and many of them are about non-riders encountering horses.

Comment: This tag is terribly misleading and totally unnecessary.

Comment: I vote for merging all equestrian tags

Comment: As we have so few horse-riding questions, a tag merge would seem reasonable (perhaps with synonyms)

Answer (score 4):

I would raise the point that hacking is one of the core non-competitive activities when riding horses, but we don't have the question numbers for the distinction to be relevant.